# Save and retrieve a form with session?

Tags: django

I have a `context_processor.py` file with the following function

```
def include_user_create(request):

    if 'form' not in request.session:
        form = CreateUserForm()
    else:
        form = request.session['form']

    return { 'create_user_form' : form }
```

I use this to display my register in my base.html template, so that I may reuse it for all pages. A function create_user handles the form submit

```
def create_user(request):

    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)            
            user.save()           
            user = authenticate(username=user.email, password=user.password)
        else:
            request.session['form'] = form #<--- save

    next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

If the form is invalid I'd like to save the form so that the `context_processor` may reuse the form, for the purpose of saving the errors so they may be displayed in the template.

Doing this gives me a error:

```
TypeError: <CreateUserForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(email;password;confirm_password)> is not JSON serializable
```

Is it possible to get this to work somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You have this error because a form object is not JSON serializable, and the default session serializer is `serializers.JSONSerializer`.

Try to change it to a pickle serializer in your `settings.py`:

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

**EDIT:**

With this setting, you don't have to care about pickle serialization, you just have to write:

```
request.session['form'] = form
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation about the picke method dumps. So far I've got request.session['form'] = pickle.dumps(self, form). I'm running this in a function based view. And it gives me a self is not defined. Can you elaborate how I'd use the PickleSerializer?

Comment: I tried and it gave me a: Can't pickle <function capfirst at 0x00000220617B7E18>: it's not the same object as django.utils.text.capfirst

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you furthermore. In french, someone says: "help yourself, then God will help you".

Comment: Thanks for you help anyhow. If I can help myself I don't need god :)